# VBA code to add line break to beginning and end of every Excel row with text

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code to add a line break at the **end** of every row in my worksheet:

```
Sub copyAndNewLine()
copy column C to D
Columns("C").Copy Destination:=Columns("D")

'loop through all cells in D and add new line
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(i, "D").Value = Cells(i, "D").Value & vbCrLf
Next i
End Sub
```

Is there a way to also loop through all cells in D and add a line break to the **beginning** of every cell? Basically, I'm doing this to create some visual space at the top and bottom of the text in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
Cells(i, "D").Value = Cells(i, "D").Value & vbCrLf
```

with:

```
Cells(i, "D").Value = vbCrLf & Cells(i, "D").Value & vbCrLf
```